# Persistence frameworks and common sense

Tags: frameworks, orm, persistence

I have studied some persistence frameworks mainly Hibernate, DORM, TMS Aurelius and I'm wondering. In a model of type:

```
TOrderFiscal < > ----- > Items < > -------- > TOrderItem ------- > TProduct

TOrderFiscal --------- > TSuplier --------- > TCidade -------- > State
```

Each class of this with countless attributes, all mapped correctly to their corresponding tables and fields. When carrying a note without using "Lazy Load" would always be done with several joins select all fields to come from each of these classes.

But it would be a waste since the note need only the supplier code and name attributes, the attributes OrderItem need only code, qty name. stock.

What solution should be taken to create a specific class supplier of note just with these attributes ? eg

```
TOrder <> ----- > Items <> -------- > TOrderItem ------- > TNotaItemProduct

TOrder -------- > TOrderSupplier
```

If this is the solution , what happens when a business rule in TProduct should also be TOrderItemProduct? I duplicate code in both classes? Do heritage, eg TORderItemProduct and TProduct both inheriting from TBaseProduct ?

Or is this a concern that we programmers we should not have ?

Comment: This is one of the reasons I do not like ORM frameworks.

Comment: @Brandon The problem is not the ORM the problem is how its being used.  Domain objects should not be mapped to a db using an ORM.

Comment: @Andy: I thought that was kinda the whole point of an ORM.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It depends on who you ask.  For trivial apps sure, but for more complex apps mapping your business / domain objects directly forces you to design your business / domain objects around the data, and reuse becomes about data, not behavior.  I like ORMs, if used correctly, because you have a strongly typed layer to access your data which can easily be code genned.  You can then really quickly find out that some column has disappeared by compiling.

Comment: @Andy If you do it like that, then you are using ORM wrong. You should design your mappings based on the domain, not other way around.

Comment: Persistence framework generate more complexity than they prevent.

Answer (score 1):

This is what we use the Hibernate Query Language (hql) for - to select only the desired data when the entire object web is not needed. For example:

```
select new map (s.code as sCode, s.name as sName, i.code as iCode, i.qty as qty, i.name as iName, i.stock as stock)
from TOrderFiscal tof 
join tof.suplier s
join tof.items i
join i.product p
where p.id = 12345;
```

You will get back a list of map of string to object, where each item in the list is a row in the result set represented as a map of the selected field aliases to the field values.